# Is there a way to connect to to aws environment to upload the spark output to s3 bucket when run locally using anaconda

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

We can do this using Dev Endpoints in aws glue but i was interested to know if it is possible to push the spark computed data(when run locally/standalone mode) to s3 using anaconda by adding spark and hadoop winutils dependences.

Comment: what about secret and access keys ? it can be done if you have access to aws s3 vpc. just like other programming like scala or java

Comment: Try to look at: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html#alternative-1-set-aws-keys-in-the-spark-context

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your local system to talk to the s3a connector, then yes.

But: I wouldn't use S3 as a direct destination of work on the local system because the performance would be atrocious and it'd take a lot of effort to get working.

Better to use the local FS as a destination and then upload it after. Lots of tools do that, including those which come on the `aws` command line app from AWS itself. You should just be able to use it to do it. And if you can do it on the command line, you can use exec() to call it in your code

```
aws s3 cp ~/work/generated s3://mybucket/results  --recursive
```